# mimic the changePage and pageinit of jquery mobile in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile

i have a two html pages `page A` and `page B` now when i move from `page A` to `page B` by using `window.location.href` on click of button which is on `page A`

now what i want is whenever `page B` loads i want to fire `load` event of `page B` only

for example , here is the content of `page B`

```
 <body>

       <div id="myList">
               <h1>Page B </h1>
      </div>

 </body>
```

i want to know two things

1. whenever `page B` loads i want to capture event `load` for `page B`
2. whenever `div` tag `myList` loads , i want to capture its `load` event too

i have tried following for `myList` load but nothing gets fired up and i dont know what should i use for specific page load i.e. only for `page B`

```
$("#myList").on('load',function(){ });
```

i am using `jqyery 1.9` , in short i want to mimic the `changePage` and `pageinit` function of jquery mobile

Answer (score 0):

I think we are way too "far into" the solution, and we need to back away to see the forest for the trees.  It seems like from the furthest distance, perhaps you probably shouldn't have two pages at all, but instead load a content box depending on a switch.

But let's ignore that for now.  If you are saying all you want is to 'count' loads coming on page B coming from page A, then we need to look at the referring URL.  That can be done easily by looking at the document.referrer value.  Thus in page B:

```
$(function(){
  var hasRun;

  if ( ! hasRun && document.referrer === '<http_path_to_doc_a>' ) {
    // do something
  }

   hasRun = true;
});
```

That should do the trick.  Notice that the $() closure executes the function once the DOM is ready.  The 'load' event only works for certain DOM elements, not an arbitrary node, as you have discovered.  I think jquery considers document.load, but I'd have to look it up to be 100% certain.  In any event, this removes the need even for that consideration.

And the hasRun flag shouldn't be needed, but one can never be too careful.  At least when it is this cheap :)

If the fully qualified HTTP/S path is too constraining, you might do a little processing on the referrer string to make matches more lenient.  For example:

```
refer_str  = document.referrer;
refer_list = refer_str.split('/');
file_name  = refer_list.pop;
file_path  = refer_list.join('/');
if ( ! hasRun && file_name === 'pageB.html' ) { ... // as before
```

Good luck!

Comment: actually i am tryin to mimic the `changePage` and `pageinit`  of jquery mobile

Answer (score 0):

The answer depends slightly on what exactly you are doing to load the page.  Within page B, you could use jQuery's [document ready](http://api.jquery.com/ready/)

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(funciton () {
        // do whatever...
    });
</script>
```

`<div id="myList">` will be loaded when that function runs.
If you are building the page with javascript you can trigger off of specific element's load events but unless you have a good reason to do this, it is not ideal because it's much slower.

Comment: actually i am tryin to mimic the `changePage` and `pageinit`  of jquery mobile

Comment: and i have common javascript file so document on ready will i think fire for all the pages

Comment: jquery mobile's idea of a data-role="page" is not the same as an entire webpage.  Perhaps you should update the question to be specific to jQuery mobile?